# Elasticsearch caching / perfomrnace issue

Tags: php, caching, yii, elasticsearch

I have an Elasticsearch cluster with 2 nodes, PHP Elasticsearch API, Yii framework.

I loop through an array of addresses and check:

**if exist continue, else insert the new address.**

The problem:

1. insert first value
2. Finish the loop process on the first address.
3. Start the next run with the 2nd address.
4. validate if address exist - this result in empty address (although I check and it was inserted)
5. new address will be inserted and now i have 2 addresses.

My question is: why does the query result in empty although data was inserted (I suspect that this is due to latency / caching) ?

------------EDIT-----------------------
Code reference:

```
$resident = Resident::model();
        if ($address) {
            $address->entity_id = $resident->id;
            if (!$resident->mailingAddress) {
                $address->default_mailing = 1;
            }
            if (!$address->save()) {
                $messages[] = [
                    'type' => 'warning',
                    'message' => 'failed',
                ];
            }
        }
```

The code is part of a much larger process but the summary is that if ($address) is always empty even when it was added to Elastic in the previous run.

Comment: What? ... Could you please include the code in question?

Comment: added code. I can't supply the whole class (which is part of a much bigger process which includes import data from file, mysql insertion and new user creation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch "publish" data regularly. The interval of publishing can be configured with `index.refresh_interval` setting ([Check this entry of the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/indices-update-settings.html)).This is an expensive operation so it's not always a good idea to have a very low refresh interval.

When indexing a document you receive a response json that tells you if the operation succeeded. So, in my opinion you can rely on that instead of checking if the document is there right after indexing.

Comment: you are correct - i do get a response if the operation was successful, the problem is I have to check if address exist since address might not appear on the first variable.
So I have to check if user already have address associated on every run, and that is when i get the false response.